# Form Array of objects using an array and an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object and an array of following kind

```
var sourceObject = { "item1" : 15 , "item2" : 20 " }
var feature =  ["field1", "field2" ]
```

I am trying to convert the above object into an array of objects.
Number of items in the object as well as the  array will be same

Resultant array of objects should like this:

```
var result = [ { "name" : "field1" , "value" : 15 } , {  "name" : "field2" , "value": 20 }]
```

The ultimate goal is to read it from the sourceObject to get the each value and then pick each value from the "feature" array toform an object

Approach I have tried so far:

```
 let result = [];
 for (let  value of Object.values(sourceObject)) {
    let row = { "field" : "XYZ" , "value": value };
    tableData.push(row);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the keys of `sourceObject` and then use `Array.map()`

```js
var sourceObject = {
  "item1": 15,
  "item2": 20
}
var feature = ["field1", "field2"]
var result = Object.keys(sourceObject).map((key, index) => {
  return {
    name: feature[index],
    value: sourceObject[key]
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object doesn't always guarantee order, so using `.values()`, `.keys()` etc... won't necessarily always guarantee your result. Instead, you can get the number from your `fieldN` string using a regular expression. Here `N` represents the `itemN` you want to retrieve from your object. Using this, you can `.map()` each `fieldN` to an object from your `sourceObject`.

See example below:

```js
const sourceObject = { "item1" : 15 , "item2" : 20 };
const feature =  ["field1", "field2" ];
const res = feature.map((name, i) => {
  const [n] = name.match(/\d+$/g);
  const value = sourceObject[`item${n}`];
  return {name, value};
});

console.log(res);
```